# Существуют ли компоненты для работы с COM (RS232) портом для Delphi XE - XE4

Tags: delphi

Надумал как-то слезть с Delphi 7 и перейти сразу на какую нибудь Delphi XE (1 или 4).
И сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой как перенести компонент Comm32 на Delphi XE.
Может кто уже справился с переносом или знает другие компоненты для работы COM (RS232) портом.

Comment: Существуют, но, наверное, хотите узнать названия этих самых компонентов?

Comment: Было бы очень интересно и мне и другим читающим данный вопрос услышать название этих компонентов, и если не трудно поделиться ссылкой.

Comment: Поищите статьи по этому поводу, насколько я помню это можно и без библиотек делать. Что то вроде открытия COM как файла. Сейчас уже не вспомню, очень давно интересовался.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свободно распостраняемый компонент для работы с COM портом персонального компьютера [BComPort](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/sources/system/2005_year/bcom_port.html).

Comment: А будет ли BComPort рабоать на Delphi XE?

Comment: да конечно, у меня работает.ХЕ2, можно установить как компонент, или же как библиотека -класс.

Answer (score 2):

Я пользовался CPortLib под дельфи 7. Может и на XE пойдут.